# On Page Load Disable Button if

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Using Mysql PHP, on one page there is a list of students with student_id, Name, 
 birthdate and few buttons on each row. I want to disable following button if student_id present in another table named 'saral_tcissue'. If student_id is not found in saral_tcissue user will able to click on button and fill the modal form. Students List is from table saral_2016 having student_id and other columns. While saral_tcissue table is also having student_id and other columns.

```html
<td>
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button" name="nirgam" id="nirgam" 
    data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target="#exampleModal" 
    data-whatever="<?php echo $row['student_id']; ?>">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>निर्गम
  </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Well, first off, you need to provide an attempt and some more code that covers the points you hinted at. Second, keep in mind that `id` must be unique across the entire DOM... so `id="nirgam"` on a 'row that is looped out' is going to cause some issues if you ever try to use it.

Comment: Please add both tables in the post. Try to use code editor in SO to make it working, this will help others to help you

Comment: Why is this a javascript or jquery issue? Just don't show the link if the student is in another table. Or show a span instead of a link

Comment: Sounds like you need a method that looks to see if the id is in another table. Since we have no clue how it works (tables,db,etc), it is impossible for us to give a real answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
 $('.btn').each(function(){
    var this_whatever=$(this).attr(data-whatever);
    if(this_whatever=='saral_tcissue'){
        this.disabled = true; 
    }
 });
```